# How to use numbered LaTeX equations using kramdown in jekyll

Tags: markdown, jekyll, mathjax, kramdown

Would it be possible to use equation numbers with the `kramdown` engine in jekyll? It seems that the previous engine `maruku` had supported equation numbering. I wanted to use equation numbering and cross-referencing supported by MathJax.

I have tried

```
$$
\begin{equation}
a + b = c \label{abc}
\end{equation}
$$

Equation \eqref{abc} is ...
```

and I obtained:

[image: a+b=c]

Comment: Why wouldn't it? What have you tried?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger I added what I have tried.

Comment: You might want to add a full example, including a markdown document, the resulting HTML, the MathJax configuration etc.

Comment: Also, you probably need both `\label{}` and `\tag{}`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$$
\begin{equation}
a + b = c \tag{abc}\label{eq:one}
\end{equation} 
$$

I refer you to e\eqref{eq:one}.
```

Comment: In my case this results in "I refer you to e(abc)" instead of the equation's number. Any idea how to solve this problem?